# Claiming a 50-move draw with a mating move

Tags: rules, checkmate, 50-move-rule, claim-draw

Under FIDE law 9.3.1, a player to move may claim a 50-move draw by writing down the intended 50th move and making the claim.

Supposing this claim is otherwise valid;  if the move would checkmate then is the game drawn?

Answer (score 3):

Mate ends the game immediately, but the mating move must be *made*, not just written down. If the player only writes the move down and claims a draw in the correct way, it's a draw (but I doubt it'll ever happen in practice).

Comment: Makes sense, but see https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/19715/12523 for an opposing view from an IA, who says "you need to consider the position as if the move had been played", also giving the example of a 50th move that makes a capture.